# generation of random binary numbers in python

Tags: random, binary, numbers

I want to print or plot list of binary numbers which are randomly generated. I have print and plot random numbers between 1 and 5000 and my code is as under;

## generation of random numbers

for a in range(0, 5000):
 a=random.sample(range(0, 5000), 5000)
 print (a)
 plt.plot(a)
 plt.show()

This code is running perfectly. 
but I want Binary numbers instead of Decimal numbers.
kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 9):

To get the binary representation of your random generated number (decimal int) , use `bin()`

**For instance,** the following code will print 10 random numbers. in decimal and binary

```
import random

for i in range(0, 10):
    a = random.randint(0, 5000)
    print a, bin(a)
```

**output:**

```
1465 0b10110111001
1624 0b11001011000
2963 0b101110010011
510 0b111111110
3653 0b111001000101
3671 0b111001010111
2624 0b101001000000
4412 0b1000100111100
3910 0b111101000110
2582 0b101000010110
```

## Online demo - https://repl.it/Dx3O

**NOTE:** in your example i saw some usage in matplotlib however you weren't explicitly asking about matplotlib so i answered more generally